# is there any remote local path for unix share similar to windows?

Tags: windows, unix, samba, smb, file-sharing

Windows local path of share: `D:\SomeFolder\Share`. 
Windows Share path for above folder: `\\ServerName\Share`. 
Windows remote local path : `\\ServerName\d$\SomeFolder\Share`

Unix local path: `/mnt/disk1/share`.
Unix share path: `smb://servername/share`.
Unix remote local path: `??`

Is there any alternative similar to `\\ServerName\d$` in unix? 
Also can we access unix's remote local path, if any, from windows machine?

Consider both windows and unix machines are in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

`\\server\d$` is a share just like `\\server\share`, the difference is that Windows automatically created it. Share names ending with $ are hidden in most places in Windows.

These drive shares can be turned off with the AutoShareWks/AutoShareServer registry values or Group Policy.

IPC$ is the only really special share and is used internally by SMB.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Is there any hidden shares in unix systems? Or anything similar to AutoShareWks/AutoShareServer registry values in unix to turn ihidden shares on/off?

Comment: @saran, no, in Linux there are no hidden shares

Answer (score 0):

You can have `/net` directory. Assuming you have rights to see particular NFS share you can reach it on this way:

```
ls /net/<server>/<path>
```

where `<server>` is the hostname or IP of server which share
`<path>` is the path of shared directory on above server